# How do I fix these iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I am trying to setup my networks firewall, and am having trouble because i keep getting kicked out of SSH because of mistakes. Here's what I currently have:

```
# Custom Rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -N mc
iptables -A mc --src 123.456.789.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mc --src 123.456.789.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mc --src 50.50.50.50 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mc -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mc -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mc -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A mc -j DROP

# Server Rules (Main Server)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 64000:64321 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --source proxy.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --source proxy.p19.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --source proxy.rbx.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --source proxy.rbx2.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --source ping.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 --source cache.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j mc
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565 -j mc
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Basically:

- Allow access to ports 64000:64321
- Allow access on TCP (from sport 53) to ports 1024:65535
- Allow access on UDP (from sport 53) to ports 1024:65535
- Allow access from ICMP ping requests, from the sources listed above
- Allow access to port 3306 using the `mc` rules
- Filter access from ports `20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565` through `mc` rules
- Deny all other input

Comment: You might want to look into iptables-apply to avoid getting kicked out every time you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "Filter access from ports 20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565 through mc rules" with this rule: 
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565 -j mc`
 will not work because of exclamation mark. Your rule works for every port except `20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565`. If you want "filter access from ports 20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565 through mc rules" you should use: 
 
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20,21,22,80,443,9987,20117,25565 -j mc`

For now in your configuration you allow ssh access only for one source addresses `cache.ovh.net` - in your main `INPUT` rules.
For connections to other ports you have rule:
`iptables -A mc -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
that  allows related and established connections to work. I think connections with source addresses from you mc custom rules should work fine, but for your main `INPUT` rule you should add something like this:
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 --source cache.ovh.net -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
right after this line:
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 --source cache.ovh.net -j ACCEPT`

Also you should check DNS settings. Does `ping.ovh.net` resolves to the right IP address?